# Margin auto nightmare

Tags: html, css, xhtml, center, margin

I'v tried every way I can think of, but for the life of me I can't figure our why the navigation menu won't center. I've tried text-align, margin-auto, block display... On both the parent and child. I'm sure it's something uber-simple but this is starting to cause hair-loss.

The demo is [available here](http://previews.tinygiantstudios.co.uk/):

If you'd like to see some code, here's the **HTML**:

```
<div id="navigation" class="col-full">

<ul id="main-nav" class="nav fl">

  <li id="menu-item-266" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-266"><a href="http://previews.tinygiantstudios.co.uk/">Home</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29"><a href="http://previews.tinygiantstudios.co.uk/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-38" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-38"><a href="http://previews.tinygiantstudios.co.uk/news/">News</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="http://previews.tinygiantstudios.co.uk/contact/">Contact</a></li>

</ul>   
</div><!-- /#navigation -->
```

And the **CSS**

```
#navigation {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #131313;
  border-top: 0px solid #DBDBDB;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #DBDBDB;
  border-left: 0px solid #DBDBDB;
  border-right: 0px solid #DBDBDB;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  font: 14px/14px sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.nav {
  z-index: 99;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.fl {
  float: left;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
}
```

Can anyone show me what I'm missing?

Thanks,

Comment: That's a sweet design. Just thought you'd like to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code to your CSS:

```
.nav {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;

  /* IE7 should be pleased */
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
```

It won't work with older versions of IE (`inline-block`), but what will?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the test page provided, and I don't see why it would anyway.

Comment: Really? I did this with Chrome's Inspector and it worked fine.

Comment: @Blender Weird, I tried it in Chrome as well and couldn't get it to work. Oh well, probably means it's time to get some sleep.

Comment: @TinyGiantStudios: I swapped my code a second ago. Try pasting that code at the end of your CSS file. (I negated your `float`).

Comment: Cool - thanks. Just made the changes and it seems to work. Any idea what can be done for IE7?

Answer (score 1):

To set margins to auto, you need to specify a width, and display the element as block.

Comment: That's what I thought it was initially as well, but it doesn't appear to work on the test page provided.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, I just tested it myself in Chrome, and it works fine.

Comment: Huh, I tried and couldn't get it to work. Oh well, probably means it's time to give my brain a rest and sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the margin to zero/automatic only works with fixed width block elements. Remove the inline float for it to take effect.

Comment: Not sure I'm following - I tried what you suggested (at least I think I did), but it's not working... Have you got any code I should try?

Comment: Ditto what Brad said above. Don't use an inline float unless you complete the block elsewhere. Set the list so that `ul` ends up with left/right margin set to `auto`, and force it to a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

For centering with `margin: 0 auto;` your element must be `display: block;`, have a *fixed* width and cannot be floated with `float`.

So you need to remove the `fl` class from your `<ul>` and give it a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

You should either specify a width for `#navigation` or `#main-nav`

Right now #navigation spans the entire width of `#wrapper` and thus cant ever center. Making it around 500px wide will fix the the issues.

If you want to center main-nav instead of navigation, you should remove the `float:left;` of it and give it a fixed width and `margin: auto;`